# proving L1* ∪ L2* ⊆ (L1∪L2)*

Tags: automata, regular-languages

x∈ L1* ∪ L2*  ⇔ x∈ L1* ∨ x ∈L2*  ⇔ x ∈(L1)* ∨ x∈(L2)* ⇔ x ∈L1* ∪ L2* ⇔ x∈(L1∪L2)*

Is it enough to prove it this way?

Comment: What is your definition of $L^*$?

Comment: L1 and L2 are languages
L*= {w1…wn | wi ∈ L,  n>=0}

Answer (score 4):

No. Your proof of $A\iff B$ is to claim that

$$A\iff \text{something} \iff \text{something else} \iff A \iff B\,.$$

The first two stages are irrelevant, since you get back to $A$. The final stage just asserts as true the exact thing you're supposed to be proving.

Try instead to prove that every string in the first language is in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove more generally that if $A \subseteq B$ then $A^* \subseteq B^*$. Indeed, if $w \in A^*$ then $w$ can be written in the form $w = w_1 \ldots w_n$ (possibly $n = 0$), where $w_1,\ldots,w_n \in A$. Since $A \subseteq B$, also $w_1,\ldots,w_n \in B$, and so $w \in B^*$.

You take it from here.

Comment: *"Let us prove more generally that if A⊆B then A∗⊆B∗"* Can you elaborate on how you proved it in your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a word in $L1^* \cup L2^*$.
Then either $x \in L1^*$ or $x \in L2^*$ (or both, but we do not have to consider that separately). Without loss of generality, let's assume $x \in L1^*$.

Then we have that $L1 \subseteq L1 \cup L2$. Using the proof by Yuval Filmus, you can prove that this implies $L1^* \subseteq (L1 \cup L2)^*$.

Therefore, every $x \in L1^*$ is in $(L1 \cup L2)^*$.